# Apache 'The Request Operation Has Failed' after inputing LoadModule

Tags: php, apache

I'm just starting out with php and Apache. When I try running my PHP code, in Chrome it simply displays the code, and on IE it displays nothing. What i try to put in:

```
<?php phpinfo();?>
```

The same thing happens to every PHP command I put in. Others have found the solution to be inputing this into their httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule php5_module "c:/php/php5apache2_4.dll"
```

But when I press start on Apache after I add that, it displays the error 'The Request Operation Has Failed'. When I remove it, Apache runs fine but the PHP has the same problem as mentioned earlier. What do I do?

Edit: This happens after I try loading any module, not just that one

Comment: The file where you write the code in ends with .php right?

Comment: are you opening a php file on the server ?

Comment: Epodax: I tried in both a .php file and and .html file, still, nothing.

Comment: Arjun: I am typing in "localhost" in the browser. I managed to display "It Works" but i couldnt get any php working.

Comment: @Ethernetz, remember to use @ before a name :) Otherwise we won't get a notification. Unless you have configured apache / php to read .html with php (which I doubt you have), use .php files. Just to be sure, you do have php installed right?

Comment: @Epodax turns out i had the wrong VC installed for the Apache. Thanks though.